# How to send credentials with a postman request that has browser pop up for credentials?

Tags: xml, google-chrome, url, postman

I have an XML feed that I am trying to access over the internet. When I open the link in a browser, it shows a pop-up as shown below image. After I enter my username and password I am able to access the feed. How do I open this link using postman?

[image]